# Android seekbar - thumb is invisible after set its drawable

Tags: android, seekbar

I have a seek bar and I am setting the thumb drawable in code. When the activity is starting I can see the changed drawable for the thumb but if I start a new activity from the seekbar activity and come back, the seekbar's thumb gets invisible (only if I set it's drawable again). This is happening only if I come back from other activity to the seekbar activity.

I need to change the drawable of the thumb in onRestart() because the other activityes may change the color or shape of the thumb and I need to refresh it's drawable.

I tried invalidate() on the seekbar but no use...

**EDIT:**
*I tried to make 3 static Drawable objects and load the images in onCreate() and I noticed that after coming back on the SeekBar activity, if I set the thumb drawable to the one that is already set, the thumb is visible but if I change the drawable, the thumb becomes invisible.*

**EDIT 2:**

In this case I set the loaded drawables to the thumb:

```
String gender = getGender();
    if (gender.equals(Profile.GENDER_1)) {
        mSeekBar.setThumb(mDrawable1);
    } else if (gender.equals(Profile.GENDER_2)) {
        mSeekBar.setThumb(mDrawable2);
    } else {
        mSeekBar.setThumb(mDrawable3);
    }
```

And this is if I try to get the drawables from the resources

String gender = getGender();

```
if (gender.equals(Profile.GENDER_1)) {
    mDrawable = mSeekBar.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.slider_thumb_1);
} else if (gender.equals(Profile.GENDER_2)) {
    mDrawable = mSeekBar.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.slider_thumb_2);
} else {
    mDrawable = mSeekBar.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.slider_thumb_3);
}

mSeekBar.setThumb(mDrawable);
```

In both cases the thumb is getting invisible..

What can be the problem? does somebody know the answer? 
Thank you!

Comment: Could you post the code you use to change the drawable?

Comment: Hm, you could try to print the value of mDrawablex after having set it to the seekbar to make sure it is a drawable and not null. (Log.i("drawable", "got drawable? "+mDrawable);

Comment: I've done this and unfortunately is not null :(, if I set the same drawable, the thumb remains visible, it hides only if I change the drawable with a different one(not a new one). Thank you for your time, again

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are not setting the drawable's bounds before using it.

Try adding this line before the setThumb() call:

```
mDrawable.setBounds(0,0, 
    mDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), 
    mDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight()
);
```

Comment: and of course Google changed the default behavior for the drawable bounds somewhere between kitkat and marshmallow.